# List installed program in windows

Tags: c++, windows

I would like to get a list of unique installed programs in windows,like in "add/remove programs" in windows. But the data at HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Uninstall,
has some duplicates. How do I filter them?

thanks

Comment: Did I get that right? If you don't like the edit, please roll back.

Answer (score 4):

The recommended Win32 way of doing this would be to use the Microsoft Installer API. The function you want is [MsiEnumProductsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370102%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: does it work with *all* the application installed or only with the ones installed via MSI?

Comment: It will display the applications that appear in Add/Remove programs.

Comment: Does it can use platform about windows 2000/XP/2003/Vista/7/2008

Comment: add/remove programs in windows 7  which the program's install date does not mach with the uninstall registry value

Answer (score 0):

The problem I encountered using a 'GetWmiObject' query of the Win32_Product table is that it expects installed programs to use a standard uuid key name, and i found that not all vendors name their registry key this way.

From powershell I did this to scan through all the keys regardless of name

```
$reg = Get-ChildItem "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" -Recurse
foreach ($a in $reg) {
    if ($a.GetValue("Publisher") -eq 'Publisher_Name') {
      Write-Output $a.GetValue("DisplayVersion")
    }
}
```